# werkzeug.routing.BuildError using redirect url_for

Tags: python, flask

Trying to pass a variable while I'm using `redirect(url_for())` I face this error:

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'view'. Did you forget to specify values ['password']?
```

Function where I call 'view' and try to specify a value to 'password':

```
@app.route('/confirmAdmin/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def confirmAdmin():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form["password"] == 'pass123':
            return redirect(url_for("view"), password='pass123')
```

View Rote:

```
@app.route('/view/<password>/')
def view(password):
    if password == 'pass123':
        return render_template("view.html", values=users.query.all())
```

I believe the error is on the first route, because i tried to access directly http://127.0.0.1:5000/view/pass123/ and it works normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer to this doc https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.url_for

change this line

```
return redirect(url_for("view"), password='pass123')
```

to

```
return redirect( url_for("view", password='pass123') )
```